# Reset ubuntu root password without GRUB?

Tags: 20.04, grub2, password, root

## ISSUE

Hi i forgot the password of my root account.

Now i found online you can go into the grub menu and reset it that way through recovery mode.

But is there any other way to do this since this doesn't work for me either?
You see when i enter the grub menu i get a command prompt where i can do nothing.

I also tried to this https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/

when i try to enter recovery i get this message "Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue)"
Instead of the press enter for maintenance one

and for the alternative option i have no kernels i only have ubuntu with Linux ... generic recovery mode.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: do you use encryption?